# Can't move #element1, why is that?

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have tried making a css rule for #element1, for all h1, etc but I can still move every object except for #element1. Is there something I'm missing?

```
    <style>
    h1{
        position:absolute;
        top:3000;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/qk0paqnob/cooltext119178095664811.jpg">

    <h2 class="post1">Web Design</h2>
    <h2 class="post2">App Development</h2>
    <h2 class="post3">IT Consulting</h2>
    <h2 class="post4">Tech Support</h2>

    <div id="1">
        <h1 id="element1">Web Design</h1>
        <p>Gunlogson is a small developmental technology business that focused of     promotional projects for small bussinesses.</p>
    </div>

    <h1 id="element2">App Development</h1>

    <h1 id="element3">IT Consulting</h1>

    <h1 id="element4">Tech Support</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: As an addendum to what @Imgonzalves said: When defining dimensions you must also define a unit (unless the value is zero).

Answer (score 4):

You need to change this to 3000px

```
h1{
    position:absolute;
    top:3000;
}
```

to

```
h1{
    position:absolute;
    top:3000px;
}
```